# Present Simple/Continuous

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous, present-simple

Can we use both present simple and continuous in this sentence?

> I've got a high temperature. I think i am coming/come down with a flu.

- **Continuous** - when we consider this to be as a process -> we have temperature so we might be coming down with a flu
- **Simple** - as a person's viewpoint - there can be many diseases but in our personal opinion it is most probably a flu

I know that according to the book it should be continuous but please help me understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we say:

> I come down with {some malady}...

we do not mean that we are becoming sick at that moment, but that we become sick  periodically or now and then.

> I come down with a cold *one or two times a year*.

The simple present (with non-stative verbs) is used to refer to an event as one occurring with some degree of regularity, or habitually.

We use the continuous if we wish to express the idea that the malady is beginning to affect us at this moment:

> I am coming down with a cold.

With a stative verb, the simple present means that the state is in effect at this moment:

> He *has* a pencil is his shirt pocket.
>
> He *has* javascript experience.

One often sees the continuous used in Indian English in contexts where American or British or Australian English would use the simple present:

<sup>Indian English</sup> He is having javascript experience.